# How can the quality of a resampling algorithm be measured?

Tags: audio, resampling, embedded-systems

I need to write my own resampling algorithm to resample sample and impulse response wav files between 44.1, 48 and 96 kHz. I'm on an embedded platform, so I don't have access to the usual libraries. The current plan is to write a resampler from scratch.

Is there anything between linear interpolation and polyphase filters as far as quality is concerned? I'm mainly interested in a simple solution, quality may suffer (for now).

I do have access to a Bluestein FFT algorithm on that platform, so FFT resampling would be an option, maybe.

Summary:

1. which resampling algorithm should I look at?
2. what are some common quality metrics?

Comment: Linear interpolation _is_ polyphase fltering -- it's just polyphase filtering with a 2-point parent anti-aliasing filter.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of quality metrics in terms of what is the absolute best one, or set, to use.  I **strongly suggest** that you, instead, ask _yourself_ what matters _to your application_.  If you're feeding acoustic data to a machine learning algorithm you probably want different resampling than if you're resampling Led Zepplin songs, and you may want yet another set of metrics if you're resampling baroque-era string ensemble music.

Comment: Do you have MATLAB?  If you're writing your own resampler, I might be able to help you with MATLAB code to compute polyphase coefficients.  It's about designing really good brickwall FIR low-pass filters.

Comment: And if you're processing .wav files, what language are you writing this code with?  It could also be done with MATLAB.  If you're doing this in Python, you need to find someone else with Python code or maybe translate my MATLAB code.

Comment: @TimWescott Actually I'm interested in exactly the opposite. Quality is not the most important aspect I was after. The quality metrics where meant as a testing utility, so that I could verify whatever algorithm I decide to take on.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I use Python + Jupyter notebooks for almost all prototypes. The final version will run on an ARM Cortex MCU with 700 Mhz. All the things around the resampling (wav-reading, convolution) already exists in C++.

Comment: @TobiasHienzsch "quality is the most important metric" but *quality* means different things to different applications. You will have to be more specific.

Comment: And if you have 32 bit MCU with fpu, then there's plenty available dsp libraries, "all the usual suspects" for c and c++, in fact. So, not quite sure you need much help. Just go and use what is out there under permissive licenses.

Answer (score 5):

> which resampling algorithm should I look at?

Polyphase FIR is the way to go. It's actually pretty east to implement from scratch. Much easier than anything FFT related. And you get a lot of knobs to twist to dial in the quality level that you need (number of phases, phase interpolation for asynchronous conversion, FIR length, etc)

> what are some common quality metrics?

Lots

- Passband amplitude distortion
- Passband phase distortion
- Passband width
- Stop band attenuation
- Transition band width
- Harmonic distortion,
- Intermodulation distortion
- Non-harmonic noise floor
- THD
- memory footprint, CPU consumption, etc.

A good test signal is a combination of a few sine waves at different frequencies. You can calculate the "ideal" answer and subtract it out from your actual result.

> I'm on an embedded platform, so I don't have access to the usual libraries.

I recommend developing the algorithm in Matlab, Python etc. and doing all the qualification and metrics there. Once fully verified and approved you only port the final version on the embedded platform and regression test it against the reference.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the terminology. I have some reading to do.

Answer (score 2):

Upsample from 44.1 to 48 kHz.  Then down sample that from 48 to 44.1 kHz.  Make sure your result is lined up with the original and subtract the original from the up and down sampled result.  The residual is error.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using interpolation for up/downsampling unless absolutely necessary, ie if you have non-uniformly spaced query points. Interpolation is fine for amplitude estimation, but is poor at estimating phase since the phase is the angle around the unit circle. You need significant oversampling to get good phase estimates.

As already mentioned, polyphase FIRs are a good option, and are by no means subpar. They are used in plenty of applications.

Comment: Yeah I mean mathematically, a polyphase resampler is no different than up sampling - combined anti-image+anti-aliasing filter - down sampling. Like, not only on par, but literally giving the bitwise same result.

Comment: @sinabala I'm not sure what exactly you mean by your comment. Are you agreeing or disagreeing?

Comment: Fully agreeing, even reinforcing: what you propose is not only *on par*, it is identical, in terms of results!

Comment: @sinabala gotcha, thanks!